# SQL disable foreign key for a while

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have a trigger `trig_1` and I want to delete something from table `tbl_1` but SQL throws an error about foreign key between `tbl_1` and `tbl_2`.

How to disable a foreign key, do the delete operation, and re-enable the foreign key?

```
create trigger trig_1
on tbl_1
for delete
as

begin
    delete from tbl_2 
    where tbl_2.ID = ID     // ID is from tbl_1 and it's a foreign key
end
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: If your delete fails because the rows are still referenced, then disabling the foreign key won't help - because you can never enable it again as the data now is invalid.

Comment: The foreign key is there **for a good reason** - if your delete doesn't work - then you're doing **something wrong** and you shouldn't try to weasel your way around it - fix the root cause of the problem!

Comment: Depends on DBMS, for example with DB2 delete triggers are allowed when ON UPDATE RESTRICT  and are not allowed when ON UPDATE NO ACTION